# AWS EC2 user data NOT executed (using python sdk boto)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sdk, amazon-ec2, user-data

I search a lot, seems nobody had any problem with this.

Probably there's a problem with my code, but I really can't find it.

this is my user-data-script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

su root
cd /var
mkdir www
```

this is the python script I'm using for launching the instance

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import boto.ec2

def get_script(filename='user-data-script.sh'):
    return open(filename).read()

def launch():
    connection = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
    return connection.run_instances(
        image_id = 'ami-6ba27502',
        instance_type = 't1.micro',
        key_name = 'forSSH',
        security_groups = ['default'],
        user_data=get_script(),
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    launch()
```

and after the instance is ready. I ssh into it, I can't find /var/www :(

this is the last few line in  /var/log/cloud-init.log

```
[CLOUDINIT] cloud-init-cfg[INFO]: cloud-init-cfg ['all', 'final']
[CLOUDINIT] __init__.py[DEBUG]: handling rightscale_userdata with freq=None and args=[]
[CLOUDINIT] __init__.py[DEBUG]: handling scripts-per-once with freq=None and args=[]
[CLOUDINIT] __init__.py[DEBUG]: handling scripts-per-boot with freq=None and args=[]
[CLOUDINIT] __init__.py[DEBUG]: handling scripts-per-instance with freq=None and args=[]
[CLOUDINIT] __init__.py[DEBUG]: handling scripts-user with freq=None and args=[]
```

ps: I'm NOT trying to setup HTTP server,

the `su root; cd /var; mkdir www` is just something to try.

Answer (score 0):

user_data script runs as root, so you don't need "su root"